# MinGW ld making DLLs into a very short file

Tags: windows, dll, mingw, .a

I want to link some .a files into a .dll file with MinGW `ld`, but it works bad:
the .a files are big, like 0.98 MB, but when I do:

> ld liba.a libb.a libc.a -shared -o final.dll

but it doesn't work well! I got an only 5 kb file `final.dll`.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* link libraries like this: `ld liba.a libb.a libc.a -shared -o final.dll`; `ld` will never select any object module from any of them, because it never has any unresolved reference to satisfy. To achieve your objective, a possible workaround would be:

```
mkdir dlltmp
cd dlltmp
ar x ../liba.a
ar x ../libb.a
ar x ../libc.a
gcc -shared -o ../final.dll *.o
```

and, to clean up afterwards:

```
cd ..
rm -rf dlltmp
```

Do note the use of `gcc` rather than `ld` here; invoking `ld` directly is almost always a *bad* idea, (and if you used it as `ld -o ../final.dll *.o`, instead of the `gcc` command I've shown here, your link will surely fail due to unresolved references). Also note that I'm assuming that your `gcc` and `ar` are the MinGW tools, and that you have a unixy `rm`, (such as MSYS provides); if your tools are not these, then you may need `mingw32-gcc`, `mingw32-ar`, (or whatever else may be appropriate for you), and some alternative command to expunge the temporary directory.